# Customize Paging SlideTabStrip Android

Tags: android, android-viewpager, spannablestring

I am working on customizing Paging Slide Strip, the Page Strip takes only Title in the heading. My requirement is a bit different, I need to have a Title as well as a Sub-Title kind of thing.
For that I have passed the `getPageTitle` in this way, and it is working ok.

```
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return (TITLES[position]+"\n"+SUBTITLE[position]);
}
```

But along with that, I need to display different Color and Font-size for my Title and Sub-Title, for that I have used SpannableString inside my custom PagingStrip class, but it does not seem to work.

Please check what I have achieved,

[image]

What I want is

[image]

Please check my code for Custom Paging Strip Class.

```
package com.astuetz;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Paint.Style;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener;
import android.text.SpannableString;
import android.text.style.ForegroundColorSpan;
import android.text.style.UnderlineSpan;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener;
import android.widget.HorizontalScrollView;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.sujit.pagestrip.R;

import java.util.Locale;


public class PagerSlidingTabStrip extends HorizontalScrollView {

    public interface IconTabProvider {
        public int getPageIconResId(int position);
    }

    // @formatter:off
    private static final int[] ATTRS = new int[] {
        android.R.attr.textSize,

    };
    // @formatter:on

    private LinearLayout.LayoutParams defaultTabLayoutParams;
    private LinearLayout.LayoutParams expandedTabLayoutParams;

    private final PageListener pageListener = new PageListener();
    public OnPageChangeListener delegatePageListener;

    private LinearLayout tabsContainer;
    private ViewPager pager;

    private int tabCount;

    private int currentPosition = 0;
    private float currentPositionOffset = 0f;

    private Paint rectPaint;
    private Paint dividerPaint;

    private int indicatorColor = 0xFF666666;
    private int underlineColor = 0x1A000000;
    private int dividerColor = 0x1A000000;

    private boolean shouldExpand = false;
    private boolean textAllCaps = true;

    private int scrollOffset = 52;
    private int indicatorHeight = 1;
    private int underlineHeight = 2;
    private int dividerPadding = 12;
    private int tabPadding = 24;
    private int dividerWidth = 0;

//  private int tabTextSize = 12;
//  private int tabTextColor = 0xFF0000FF;
//  private int tabTypefaceStyle = Typeface.BOLD;

    private int lastScrollX = 0;

    private int tabBackgroundResId = R.drawable.background_tab;

    private Locale locale;

    public PagerSlidingTabStrip(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public PagerSlidingTabStrip(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public PagerSlidingTabStrip(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

        setFillViewport(true);
        setWillNotDraw(false);

        tabsContainer = new LinearLayout(context);
        tabsContainer.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        tabsContainer.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        addView(tabsContainer);

        DisplayMetrics dm = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();

        scrollOffset = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, scrollOffset, dm);
        indicatorHeight = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, indicatorHeight, dm);
        underlineHeight = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, underlineHeight, dm);
        dividerPadding = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dividerPadding, dm);
        tabPadding = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, tabPadding, dm);
        dividerWidth = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dividerWidth, dm);
    //  tabTextSize = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, tabTextSize, dm);

        // get system attrs (android:textSize and android:textColor)

        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, ATTRS);

    //  tabTextSize = a.getDimensionPixelSize(0, tabTextSize);
        //tabTextColor = a.getColor(1, tabTextColor);

        a.recycle();

        // get custom attrs

        a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.PagerSlidingTabStrip);

        indicatorColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.PagerSlidingTabStrip_pstsIndicatorColor, indicatorColor);
        underlineColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.PagerSlidingTabStrip_pstsUnderlineColor, underlineColor);
        dividerColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.PagerSlidingTabStrip_pstsDividerColor, dividerColor);
        indicatorHeight = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.PagerSlidingTabStrip_pstsIndicatorHeight, indicatorHeight);
        underlineHeight = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.PagerSlidingTabStrip_pstsUnderlineHeight, underlineHeight);
        dividerPadding = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.PagerSlidingTabStrip_pstsDividerPadding, dividerPadding);
        tabPadding = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.PagerSlidingTabStrip_pstsTabPaddingLeftRight, tabPadding);
        tabBackgroundResId = a.getResourceId(R.styleable.PagerSlidingTabStrip_pstsTabBackground, tabBackgroundResId);
        shouldExpand = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.PagerSlidingTabStrip_pstsShouldExpand, shouldExpand);
        scrollOffset = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.PagerSlidingTabStrip_pstsScrollOffset, scrollOffset);
        textAllCaps = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.PagerSlidingTabStrip_pstsTextAllCaps, textAllCaps);

        a.recycle();

        rectPaint = new Paint();
        rectPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        rectPaint.setStyle(Style.FILL);

        dividerPaint = new Paint();
        dividerPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        dividerPaint.setStrokeWidth(dividerWidth);

        defaultTabLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        expandedTabLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1.0f);

        if (locale == null) {
            locale = getResources().getConfiguration().locale;
        }
    }

    public void setViewPager(ViewPager pager) {
        this.pager = pager;

        if (pager.getAdapter() == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("ViewPager does not have adapter instance.");
        }

        pager.setOnPageChangeListener(pageListener);

        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void setOnPageChangeListener(OnPageChangeListener listener) {
        this.delegatePageListener = listener;
    }

    public void notifyDataSetChanged() {

        tabsContainer.removeAllViews();

        tabCount = pager.getAdapter().getCount();

        for (int i = 0; i < tabCount; i++) {

            if (pager.getAdapter() instanceof IconTabProvider) {
                addIconTab(i, ((IconTabProvider) pager.getAdapter()).getPageIconResId(i));
            } else {

                addTextTab(i, pager.getAdapter().getPageTitle(i).toString());
            }

        }

        updateTabStyles();

        getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            @SuppressLint("NewApi")
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                    getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                } else {
                    getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                }

                currentPosition = pager.getCurrentItem();
                scrollToChild(currentPosition, 0);
            }
        });

    }

    private void addTextTab(final int position, String title) {

        TextView tab = new TextView(getContext());

        int j=0,k=0;

        for(int i=0;i<title.length();i++){

            if(title.charAt(i)=='\n'){
                k=title.length();
                break;
            }
            j=i;
        }

        SpannableString str = new SpannableString(title);
    str.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.GREEN),0,j+1,0);
    str.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE),j+1,k,0);

      //  tab.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
        tab.setText(str);
        tab.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        //tab.setSingleLine();

        addTab(position, tab);
    }

    private void addIconTab(final int position, int resId) {

        ImageButton tab = new ImageButton(getContext());
        tab.setImageResource(resId);

        addTab(position, tab);

    }

    private void addTab(final int position, View tab) {
        tab.setFocusable(true);
        tab.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                pager.setCurrentItem(position);
            }
        });

        tab.setPadding(tabPadding, 0, tabPadding, 0);
        tabsContainer.addView(tab, position, shouldExpand ? expandedTabLayoutParams : defaultTabLayoutParams);
    }

    private void updateTabStyles() {

        for (int i = 0; i < tabCount; i++) {

            View v = tabsContainer.getChildAt(i);

            v.setBackgroundResource(tabBackgroundResId);

            if (v instanceof TextView) {

                TextView tab = (TextView) v;
        //      tab.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, tabTextSize);
        //      tab.setTypeface(tabTypeface, tabTypefaceStyle);
            //  tab.setTextColor(tabTextColor);

                // setAllCaps() is only available from API 14, so the upper case is made manually if we are on a
                // pre-ICS-build
                if (textAllCaps) {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
                        tab.setAllCaps(true);
                    } else {

                    //  tab.setText(tab.getText().toString().toUpperCase(locale));
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }

    private void scrollToChild(int position, int offset) {

        if (tabCount == 0) {
            return;
        }

        int newScrollX = tabsContainer.getChildAt(position).getLeft() + offset;

        if (position > 0 || offset > 0) {
            newScrollX -= scrollOffset;
        }

        if (newScrollX != lastScrollX) {
            lastScrollX = newScrollX;
            scrollTo(newScrollX, 0);
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        if (isInEditMode() || tabCount == 0) {
            return;
        }

        final int height = getHeight();

        // draw indicator line

        rectPaint.setColor(indicatorColor);

        // default: line below current tab
        View currentTab = tabsContainer.getChildAt(currentPosition);
        float lineLeft = currentTab.getLeft();
        float lineRight = currentTab.getRight();

        // if there is an offset, start interpolating left and right coordinates between current and next tab
        if (currentPositionOffset > 0f && currentPosition < tabCount - 1) {

            View nextTab = tabsContainer.getChildAt(currentPosition + 1);
            final float nextTabLeft = nextTab.getLeft();
            final float nextTabRight = nextTab.getRight();

            lineLeft = (currentPositionOffset * nextTabLeft + (1f - currentPositionOffset) * lineLeft);
            lineRight = (currentPositionOffset * nextTabRight + (1f - currentPositionOffset) * lineRight);
        }

        canvas.drawRect(lineLeft, height - indicatorHeight, lineRight, height, rectPaint);

        // draw underline

        rectPaint.setColor(underlineColor);
        canvas.drawRect(0, height - underlineHeight, tabsContainer.getWidth(), height, rectPaint);

        // draw divider

        dividerPaint.setColor(dividerColor);
        for (int i = 0; i < tabCount - 1; i++) {
            View tab = tabsContainer.getChildAt(i);
            canvas.drawLine(tab.getRight(), dividerPadding, tab.getRight(), height - dividerPadding, dividerPaint);
        }
    }

    private class PageListener implements OnPageChangeListener {

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            currentPosition = position;
            currentPositionOffset = positionOffset;

            scrollToChild(position, (int) (positionOffset * tabsContainer.getChildAt(position).getWidth()));

            invalidate();

            if (delegatePageListener != null) {
                delegatePageListener.onPageScrolled(position, positionOffset, positionOffsetPixels);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
            if (state == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                scrollToChild(pager.getCurrentItem(), 0);
            }

            if (delegatePageListener != null) {
                delegatePageListener.onPageScrollStateChanged(state);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            if (delegatePageListener != null) {
                delegatePageListener.onPageSelected(position);
            }
        }

    }

    public void setIndicatorColor(int indicatorColor) {
        this.indicatorColor = indicatorColor;
        invalidate();
    }

    public void setIndicatorColorResource(int resId) {
        this.indicatorColor = getResources().getColor(resId);
        invalidate();
    }

    public int getIndicatorColor() {
        return this.indicatorColor;
    }

    public void setIndicatorHeight(int indicatorLineHeightPx) {
        this.indicatorHeight = indicatorLineHeightPx;
        invalidate();
    }

    public int getIndicatorHeight() {
        return indicatorHeight;
    }

    public void setUnderlineColor(int underlineColor) {
        this.underlineColor = underlineColor;
        invalidate();
    }

    public void setUnderlineColorResource(int resId) {
        this.underlineColor = getResources().getColor(resId);
        invalidate();
    }

    public int getUnderlineColor() {
        return underlineColor;
    }

    public void setDividerColor(int dividerColor) {
        this.dividerColor = dividerColor;
        invalidate();
    }

    public void setDividerColorResource(int resId) {
        this.dividerColor = getResources().getColor(resId);
        invalidate();
    }

    public int getDividerColor() {
        return dividerColor;
    }

    public void setUnderlineHeight(int underlineHeightPx) {
        this.underlineHeight = underlineHeightPx;
        invalidate();
    }

    public int getUnderlineHeight() {
        return underlineHeight;
    }

    public void setDividerPadding(int dividerPaddingPx) {
        this.dividerPadding = dividerPaddingPx;
        invalidate();
    }

    public int getDividerPadding() {
        return dividerPadding;
    }

    public void setScrollOffset(int scrollOffsetPx) {
        this.scrollOffset = scrollOffsetPx;
        invalidate();
    }

    public int getScrollOffset() {
        return scrollOffset;
    }

    public void setShouldExpand(boolean shouldExpand) {
        this.shouldExpand = shouldExpand;
        requestLayout();
    }

    public boolean getShouldExpand() {
        return shouldExpand;
    }

    public boolean isTextAllCaps() {
        return textAllCaps;
    }

    public void setAllCaps(boolean textAllCaps) {
        this.textAllCaps = textAllCaps;
    }

    /*public void setTextSize(int textSizePx) {
        this.tabTextSize = textSizePx;
        updateTabStyles();
    }*/

    /*public int getTextSize() {
        return tabTextSize;
    }*/

    /*public void setTextColor(int textColor) {
    //  this.tabTextColor = textColor;
        updateTabStyles();
    }*/

    /*public void setTextColorResource(int resId) {
    //  this.tabTextColor = getResources().getColor(resId);
        updateTabStyles();
    }*/

    /*public int getTextColor() {
        return tabTextColor;
    }*/

    /*public void setTypeface(Typeface typeface, int style) {
        this.tabTypeface = typeface;
        this.tabTypefaceStyle = style;
        updateTabStyles();
    }*/

    public void setTabBackground(int resId) {
        this.tabBackgroundResId = resId;
    }

    public int getTabBackground() {
        return tabBackgroundResId;
    }

    public void setTabPaddingLeftRight(int paddingPx) {
        this.tabPadding = paddingPx;
        updateTabStyles();
    }

    public int getTabPaddingLeftRight() {
        return tabPadding;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state) {
        SavedState savedState = (SavedState) state;
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedState.getSuperState());
        currentPosition = savedState.currentPosition;
        requestLayout();
    }

    @Override
    public Parcelable onSaveInstanceState() {
        Parcelable superState = super.onSaveInstanceState();
        SavedState savedState = new SavedState(superState);
        savedState.currentPosition = currentPosition;
        return savedState;
    }

    static class SavedState extends BaseSavedState {
        int currentPosition;

        public SavedState(Parcelable superState) {
            super(superState);
        }

        private SavedState(Parcel in) {
            super(in);
            currentPosition = in.readInt();
        }

        @Override
        public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
            super.writeToParcel(dest, flags);
            dest.writeInt(currentPosition);
        }

        public static final Creator<SavedState> CREATOR = new Creator<SavedState>() {
            @Override
            public SavedState createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
                return new SavedState(in);
            }

            @Override
            public SavedState[] newArray(int size) {
                return new SavedState[size];
            }
        };
    }

}
```

Am I doing something wrong?
Please check the addTextTab(final int position, String title), 
that is where I have added the SpannableString logic.

Comment: in your `addTextTab` why not just replace `new TextView()` with `new LinearLayout` and give it two `TextView`s as children?

Comment: Did not think that way, should definitely try and will inform you. Thanks for the idea though

Comment: Blundell, thanks for the suggestion but can you tell me why does the Spannable does not work in the Title?
I found that to be very strange and unknown.

Comment: I avoid Spannables, I will link this to someone who loves them, see what he  says

Comment: Is this PagerSlidingTabStrip by jpardogo, a fork of the now stale one by astuetz? I'd recommend using a custom tab, and use a LinearLayout as Blundell says, rather than faffing about with spannables. (@blundell I don't love them :p)

Comment: is `textAllCaps` ever used/set to true? This method removes any previous formatting (see [here][1]).

Comment: you could try this other sliding tab library https://github.com/novoda/spikes/tree/master/landing-strip which allows you to customise the views pretty easily (see https://github.com/novoda/spikes/blob/master/landing-strip/demo/src/main/java/com/novoda/landingstrip/CustomTabActivity.java )

Comment: I changed my mind, backing @AlexCurran's horse!

Comment: Alex Curran, i am afraid that is not correct !

Comment: @akash89 Alex's observation is correct - `textAllCaps` is implemented using a spannable, and unless you build your own spannables carefully, it'll will remove anything you've done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, from your question and requirements, it seems your problem is that you want to display more than just a single String per tab, but are limited because the default implementation uses `CharSequence getPageTitle(int position)`. Instead of using a spannable to force a line break, you can use a custom tab.

[PagerSlidingTabStrip](https://github.com/jpardogo/PagerSlidingTabStrip) has an interface called `PagerSlidingTabStrip.CustomTabProvider` which you can implement on your PagerAdapter. If your PagerAdapter implements this interface, then the PagerSlidingTabStrip will not use the default tab view, nor will it try to bind data to the tab using `getPageTitle(int position)`.

Instead it delegates this responsibility to your PagerAdapter - this lets you inflate the view you want to use as a tab, and bind data to it, no restrictions:

[image: example of custom tab]

Above you can see I have a two level custom tab - this is a LinearLayout with two TextViews - where I bind data from the following enum:

```
private enum MyData {
    HELLO,
    WORLD,
    WHAT,
    IS,
    THE,
    HAPS;

    String getFirstLine() {
        return name();
    }

    String getSecondLine() {
        return "2_" + name() + "_2";
    }
}
```

My PagerAdapter is just a naive implementation of PagerAdapter, but the important addition is the `implements clause`:

```
private static class MyAdapter extends PagerAdapter
        implements PagerSlidingTabStrip.CustomTabProvider {

    ...

    @Override
    public View getCustomTabView(ViewGroup viewGroup, int position) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext());
        MyCustomTabView tabView = (MyCustomTabView) layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.view_custom_tab, viewGroup, false);
        tabView.setFirstLineText(MyData.values()[position].getFirstLine());
        tabView.setSecondLineTextView(MyData.values()[position].getSecondLine());
        return tabView;
    }
}
```

In this case, you don't need to rely on the single `CharSequence` returned by `getPageTitle(int position)` because you're being explicit in your binding of data. You can see the full adapter [here](https://github.com/ataulm/android-basic/blob/f78a12706048ad6d64ad57fe1dc4d87ccfd8d140/mobile/src/main/java/com/ataulm/basic/MyActivity.java).

Answer (score 0):

Your suggesstion was a great way out, however I have used the getPageTitle to return the split string and added the string to two different textview with different styles and added the same to a linear la}yout.

Please see my code

```
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return (TITLES[position]+"\n"+cardNoList.get(position));
        }
```

And my

```
private void addTextTab(final int position, String title) {

        LayoutParams titleLayout = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT );

        LinearLayout linLayout = new LinearLayout(getContext());
        linLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        linLayout.setLayoutParams(titleLayout);


        TextView titleText = new TextView(getContext());
        titleText.setText(title.split("\n")[0]);
        titleText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

        TextView subTitle = new TextView(getContext());
        subTitle.setText(title.split("\n")[1]);
        subTitle.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);


        imvArrow = new ImageView(getContext());
        imvArrow.setImageResource(R.drawable.icn_arrow_up_blue_large);
        imvArrow.setVisibility(GONE);

        linLayout.addView(titleText);
        linLayout.addView(subTitle);
        linLayout.addView(imvArrow);
        addTab(position, linLayout);
    }
```

For further customiztion you can use this code.

```
 private class PageListener implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {

        public int prevPage = 0;
        public int curPage = 0;

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            currentPosition = position;
            currentPositionOffset = positionOffset;

            scrollToChild(position, (int) (positionOffset * tabsContainer.getChildAt(position).getWidth()));

            invalidate();

            if (delegatePageListener != null) {
                delegatePageListener.onPageScrolled(position, positionOffset, positionOffsetPixels);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
            if (state == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                scrollToChild(pager.getCurrentItem(), 0);
            }

            if (delegatePageListener != null) {
                delegatePageListener.onPageScrollStateChanged(state);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {

            //MYcode
            prevPage = curPage;
            curPage = position;

            /*TextView tab = (TextView) tabsContainer.getChildAt(prevPage);
            tab.setTextColor(tabTextColor);

            tab = (TextView) tabsContainer.getChildAt(curPage);
            tab.setTextColor(tabActiveTextColor);*/

            LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) tabsContainer.getChildAt(prevPage);
            TextView titleText = (TextView) ll.getChildAt(0);
            titleText.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.accounts_darkgray_text));
            imvArrow = (ImageView)ll.getChildAt(2);
            imvArrow.setVisibility(GONE);

            ll = (LinearLayout) tabsContainer.getChildAt(curPage);
            titleText = (TextView) ll.getChildAt(0);
            titleText.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));
            imvArrow = (ImageView)ll.getChildAt(2);
            imvArrow.setVisibility(VISIBLE);

            if (delegatePageListener != null) {
                delegatePageListener.onPageSelected(position);
            }
        }

    }
```